# Codeigniter 2.2 and Ion Auth losing userdata after redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect

So, upon login, Ion Auth uses `$this->session->user_setdata()` to establish the session information and redirects to the main page. Then in MY_Controller we use Ion Auth's logged_in() method which checks for that information using `$this->session->userdata('identity')` to see if the user is logged in.

Before the redirect all the userdata is set as seen by `$this->session->all_userdata()` but upon entering MY_Controller none of it is there and causes the application to redirect back to the login page.

I WAS on 2.1.4 but upgraded to 2.2 and its happening in both versions.

Comment: could you post some chunk of code

Comment: i want you to post some code for more calrification

Comment: this problem is happening in all browsers??

Comment: $this->session->userdata('identity'); does not work as the new controller has no knowledge of the auth controller session. **create a new controller parent class like MY_Controller in the application/core directory. This class loads common libraries/packages (like session and ion_auth). You could also autoload the libraries and helpers.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem using [Flexi Auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/) and it was completely maddening.  We found a workaround by enabling encryption of the cookies with the setting `sess_encrypt_cookie` in `application/config/config.php`.  (See: [Session Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)).

Stepping through our app with xdebug, we could see the PHP session getting regenerated when cookies were not encrypted.  Enabling encryption of the cookies bypasses the block of code in the framework that keeps regenerating the session ID.  The problem seems to be entirely contained in the CI framework with its handling of sessions.

***EDIT***

If it helps, here is the session configuration in our `config.php`:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']             = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']              = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']              = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']                = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;`
```

The settings we have changed are the `sess_encrypt_cookie`, as previously mentioned, plus driving the sessions from the database, `sess_use_database` is `TRUE`.  For what it is worth, we do have both Ion Auth and Flexi Auth running in the same CI application.  I looked at our Ion Auth config and it is mostly the stock settings.  The settings we changed wouldn't relate to the session (password length, etc.).

Comment: This ALMOST fixes my problem. I can now redirect without a login loop but if i login / logout / login and try to logout a second time it now saves my session until I manually clear my cache instead of when clicking logout...sigh